# how to import a sheet of an excel file into the access database?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I want to import a sheet of an excel file into the access database

```
Private Sub Commande9_Click()
Dim filepath As String

filepath = "C:\Users\TXZG6067\Desktop\com.xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ImportFromExcel", filepath, True

End Sub
```

Please i need your help,thank you.

Comment: what's not happening/is happening?

Comment: I have an excel file that contains multiple sheets and I want to import just one sheet

Comment: add a range to import then.  Look at the help for TransferSpreadsheet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the worksheet name:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ImportFromExcel", filepath, True, "WorksheetName$"
```

or:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ImportFromExcel", filepath, True, "WorksheetName!"
```

Comment: I've added another option to the answer.

Comment: Error excecution '3011'

Answer (score 1):

To Import a Excel file or one of its sheet to Database, you have to follow some steps:

1) Convert that sheet/File to comma-delimiter. Use `Save as` option to convert.

2) Read this file using `StreamReader` class. Validate Columns length and the data that every column contains.

3) create a query using `StringBuilder` class (recommended) but you can also use a `string` too. Such as:

```
StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder("Insert Into table_name Values(");
foreach(row in dt.rows)
{
  sb = null;
  int j = 1;
  for(int i=0; i<columns_Count-1 ; i++) //Column count minus one to handle last column data
  {
   Sb.Append("'"+row[0][i]+"',"); 
   j++;
  }
  if(j == columns_Count) //last column appends data without comma
  {
  Sb.Append("'"+row[0][columns_Count]+"'");
  }
  Sb.Append(")");
 //execute insert query here
}
```

Comment: This might work, but is needlessly complex. Access has functionality to import Excel files. Changing file type first and then importing the changed file shouldn't be necessary. Furthermore, Access also has built-in functionality to import CSV files which you aren't utilizing. You're re-inventing the wheel twice (although it might be a more robust wheel). Attention should be focused on the specific error in DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet and fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in Excel VBA (ADO), assuming that your data is in Column A to C and so forth..

```
Dim dbpath as String, _
    x as long, _
    rs As ADODB.Recordset, _
    cn As ADODB.Connection

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

dbPath = /your db path

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
rs.Open "Consolidated", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

For x = 2 To LastRow
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Fieldnm1") = Range("A" & x).value
    rs.Fields("Fieldnm2") = Range("B" & x).value
    rs.Fields("Fieldnm3") = Range("C" & x).value
    rs.Update
Next x

rs.Close

Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 , _
"TableOrQuery","YourExcelPath", _
True, "TheNameofTheSheetYouWant"
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT i just wanted to edit to give a explanation with it, but there were already 3 answers with sufficient explanations so i didn't... but i will notice now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:
`expression .TransferSpreadsheet(TransferType, SpreadsheetType, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, Range, UseOA)`

Example:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 3, _ 
 "Employees","C:\Lotus\Newemps.wk3", True, "A1:G12"
```

You must give it the SpreadsheetType, for details about `SpreadsheetType` see below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196017.aspx

Comment: Is what you can write me the code I did not well understand please